# Exclude non-autoproperties from serialization in Json.Net

Tags: c#, serialization, json.net

I want to serialize a set of 3rd party structs, but they have a lot of properties that I dont need to serialize. I want to exclude non-autoproperties from serialization (because all that properties not automatic).

How could I do that via CustomContractResolver or somehow else?
And in the same time I want to include serialization of private fields.

What is correct way to implement this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can Achieve this by writing a custom `JsonConverter`. here is an example (I tried to write the custom serializer as general as possible, so it should work for your type with no or subtle changes):

**Custom Type and Usage:**

```
[JsonConverter(typeof (CustomSerializer))]
public struct CustomStruct
{
    public int PublicInt;
    private int _privateInt;
    public string PublicString;
    private string _privateString;

    public int AutoInt { get; set; }
    public string AutoString { get; set; }

    public int ManualInt 
    {
        get{return _privateInt;}
        set { _privateInt = value; }
    }

    public string ManualString
    {
        get { return _privateString; }
        set { _privateString = value; }
    }
}

class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var obj = new CustomStruct()
        {
            AutoInt = 10,
            AutoString = "autostring",
            ManualInt = 5,
            ManualString = "manualstring",
            PublicInt = 20,
            PublicString = "publicstring"
        };

        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj,Formatting.Indented);

        var dObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CustomStruct>(json);
    }
}
```

we expect our json result to be similar to

```
{
  "AutoInt": 10,
  "AutoString": "autostring",
  "PublicInt": 20,
  "_privateInt": 5,
  "PublicString": "publicstring",
  "_privateString": "manualstring"
}
```

**How it Works:**

C# compiler will create a Back field for every Auto Property with a name with pattern `<PropertName>k__BackingField` , so basically we can take advantage of this pattern and find them.( Note: this snippet may not work with Mono, or future .Net compilers)

```
    public static bool IsAutoProperty(PropertyInfo prop)
    {
        return prop.DeclaringType.GetFields(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance)
                                 .Any(f => f.Name.Contains("<" + prop.Name + ">"));
    }
```

Next step is trivial, we should implement a Custom Json serializer based on `JsonConverter` class.

**Custom Serializer:**

```
public class CustomSerializer : JsonConverter
{

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return typeof (CustomSerializer) == objectType;
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var jObject = JObject.Load(reader);

        var value = existingValue ?? Activator.CreateInstance(objectType);

        PopulateAutoProperties(objectType, jObject, value);
        PopulateFields(objectType, jObject, value);

        return value;
    }

    private static void PopulateAutoProperties(Type objectType, JObject jObject, object value)
    {
        var properties =
            objectType.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic);

        foreach (var p in properties.Where(IsAutoProperty))
        {
            var token = jObject[p.Name];
            var obj = token != null
                ? token.ToObject(p.PropertyType)
                : p.PropertyType.IsValueType ? Activator.CreateInstance(p.PropertyType) : null;

            p.SetValue(value, obj);
        }
    }
    private static void PopulateFields(Type objectType, JObject jObject, object value)
    {
        var fields =
            objectType.GetFields(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic);

        foreach (var f in fields.Where(f => !f.Name.Contains("<")))
        {
            var token = jObject[f.Name];
            var obj = token != null
                ? token.ToObject(f.FieldType)
                : f.FieldType.IsValueType ? Activator.CreateInstance(f.FieldType) : null;

            f.SetValue(value, obj);
        }
    }


    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var objectType=value.GetType();

        writer.WriteStartObject();

        WriteAutoProperties(writer, value, serializer, objectType);
        WriteFields(writer, value, serializer, objectType);

        writer.WriteEndObject();
    }

    private static void WriteFields(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer, Type objectType)
    {
        var fields = objectType.GetFields(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
        foreach (var f in fields.Where(f => !f.Name.Contains("<")))
        {
            writer.WritePropertyName(f.Name);
            serializer.Serialize(writer, f.GetValue(value));
        }
    }

    private static void WriteAutoProperties(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer, Type objectType)
    {
        var properties =
            objectType.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
        foreach (var p in properties.Where(IsAutoProperty))
        {
            writer.WritePropertyName(p.Name);
            serializer.Serialize(writer, p.GetValue(value));
        }
    }

    public static bool IsAutoProperty(PropertyInfo prop)
    {
        return prop.DeclaringType.GetFields(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance)
                                 .Any(f => f.Name.Contains("<" + prop.Name + ">"));
    }
}
```